# jQuery Autocomplete with PHP file that checks for names

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I want to make an autocomplete input box that uses a PHP file same as in [this w3schools tutorial.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

I want to use the jQuery Autocomplete UI to do this. I tried it like this:

```
    <input id="name" name="q">

<script>
    $('#name').autocomplete({
        source: 'ajax-suggest.php'
    });
</script>
```

What's the problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't explain your question very well. What issue are you experiencing? What errors do you get?

Comment: You might want to add a [mre] here. I mean, we're supposed to figure out what `ajax-suggest.php` does by guessing?

Comment: I don't understand how can I make it work like in the w3schools tutorial. I want it to suggest names with the autocomplete jQuery feature. It doesn't output anything and I don't get any errors.

Comment: the ajax-suggest.php is same as in the w3schools tutorial

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood, you want to have the available tags through an ajax call.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

From the official doc (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), the availableTags is an array

I think what you want is this: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: If I would write for example ajax-suggest.php?q=a it would output words like this-> Andre\tAlex\t etc. So they are separated by a tab. I guess I need to transform all the suggested words into an array like this-> [Andre,Alex]. I don't understand how can I achieve this.

Comment: In the PHP script you can return a JSON object.